# Falha no uso de JSON no INTEL XDK

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, mobile, intel-xdk

Estou fazendo uma aplicação no INTEL XDK, na qual preciso conectar com o Banco de dados. Criei o PHP para retornar com JSON e no Intel, fiz a função pra retornar tais dados. Porém a aplicação não está retornando nada, e como nunca fiz nada nessa área, decidi vir aqui pedir ajuda.
Códigos :

**JSON.PHP**

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $conecta = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=**** user=****** password=******");
    $sql = "select * from oi";
    $resultado= pg_query($conecta, $sql); 

echo '{"produto":}';
$saida = "[";

while($r = pg_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    if($saida != "["){$saida.= ", ";}
    $saida.= '{"Produto":"'.$r["nomeprod"].'"}';

}
$saida.="}}";
echo $saida;

        ?>
```

**App.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://200.145.153.172/bruno_pereira/TCC/json.php",
    dataType:"json"
}).done(function(data){
        var mostra = "";
        $.each(data.produto, function(i,x){
            mostra+= "<li>"+x.Produto+"</li>";
        });
$("#result").html(mostra);        
            });
});
```

Comment: olá! Primeiro, você está executando a página a partir do _localhost_ ? Do contrário não irá mostrar nada mesmo. Também não sei se é o caso, mas para transformar o array em JSON, você poderia usar a função [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) .

Comment: Então, eu utilizo o WinSCP para hostear tudo em uma máquina do meu colégio.. No caso esta máquina (200.145.153.172

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Tente alterar o `php` para chamar a função `json_encode` para fazer a codificação automaticamente, assim você não precisa montar o JSON manualmente:

**PHP**

```
$conecta = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=**** user=****** password=******");
$sql = "select * from oi";
$resultado= pg_query($conecta, $sql); 

$r['dados'] = $resultado; 
echo json_encode($resultado);

    ?>
```

E mostrando caso a requisição tenha sucesso:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://200.145.153.172/bruno_pereira/TCC/json.php",
  dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(data){
         var mostra = "";
         for (i=0; i< data.dados.length;i++){
           mostra+= "<li>"+data.dados[i].nome_do_campo_desejado+"</li>";
           /* esse nome do campo desejado deve ser o nome de algum campo desejado que tenha 
              sido pesquisado no SELECT do PHP */
         }



$("#result").html(mostra);        
        });
});
```